# Android Retrofit, how to block multiple copies of same request

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

How to block sending multiple copies of same request, I like to reject the request if the request is already sent and waiting for response.

Comment: You can always use a bool variable "isRunning" to check if its already running. In request completion block mark the variable false. When request starts mark the variable true. To identify between different requests you can use tags for each request.

Comment: Use a Hashmap. Whenever you start a request. Add it into hashmap. Hashmap<YourURL,true>.
When the request ends, remove from the map. Hashmap.remove(yourURL)
During start, you can check if hashmap.contains(yourURL), if it returns true, it means that request is still running.

Comment: Perhaps, @sino-k-d could add more information about his use case. Eg: is the request happening on a button press OR is it once manually OR he wants to implement an application level caching solution.

Answer (score 0):

You cold keep your data in the repository or class from where you are firing the request and keep it updating as you do so.

Use a Set in the class as Set. Before you make a request check in the set if it already exists. If it does, then you neither have to update the set nor send it. If the request is not present in the Set then add the request in the Set and send it.

Upon completion of the request remove that request from the Set.

Hope this method is more optimised for your use-case.